# #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1 when enabling Auto_increment

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment, mysql-error-1075

When I'm trying to enable `auto_increment` on a column in phpmyadmin, but I always get this error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 1
```

The column in question is the PK and an INT. It already has several rows in it. Because of this, I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=7
```

This should have set the auto incrementing to start at 7, and so skipping the 0 to 6 that already exist in that row... but it didn't work. Or that was the theory.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:**

I have tried removing the PK index on the column and running a query setting the column to `NULL`. Everything was set to `NULL`. I tried to then add `auto increment` and I got the following error: `#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`. I try to add a PK index again and get the following `#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 1`. Argh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to add an `auto_increment` to an existing table, you need to make sure all of the key values already in the table are all unique.

Setting the column value to `NULL` should work. mySQL will then auto-fill the values with auto increment ones.

Comment: So go through that column and replace it with `NULL`s and try again?

Comment: @Django yeah, or just `UPDATE table SET columnname = NULL`

Comment: @Django Yes, update table column with null (be sure to remove key constraints), then create autoincrement primary key.Mysql will do rest for you.

Comment: @Pekka Ugh :( Thanks for the help, but I get the same message when I run that query: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 1 `

Comment: @Django does your column have a default value?

Comment: @Pekka No, there's no default value.

Comment: @Django ahh, maybe it has to be nullable, too? I can't remember right now and I can't try out. Can you try making the column `NULL` and run it again?

Comment: @Pekka Ok, I removed the PK index and ran the query, switched it to nullable. Now everything is set to `NULL`. I try to then add auto increment and I get the following error: `#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`. I try to add a PK index again and get the following `#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 1`. Argh.

Comment: @Django ugh! Does it have to be a primary key though? Can you try just creating a normal index and then setting the auto increment?

Comment: @Django creating a normal index and then imposing the `auto_increment` seems to work for me.

Comment: @Pekka Hurrah! Setting it to an normal index worked! (I've since switched it to a PK -- and it still works.) What a nightmare. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    `alter table Persons modify id integer unsigned primary key auto_increment;`

were id is the column of interest

Comment: I would have tried this, but I just fixed the problem. Thanks for trying.